# how to list top 100 blobs from azure blob storage using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using this code and could get the result but dont think this is a proper way

```
CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = 
container.GetDirectoryReference(blobDirectoryReference);

IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList =  
blobDirectory.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing:true, 
blobListingDetails:BlobListingDetails.Metadata)
.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Properties.LastModified).Take(100);
```

Comment: If this code works, what's your question?

Comment: I want to fetch top 100 rows , but I think this code fetches all the rows and than select 100.

Comment: You code is getting all of the rows, sorting them, and then taking 100 based on your sort order. Is sorting required for your scenario? This isn't clear from the question. If you just want the top 100 in lexicographic order then you can remove the `OrderByDescending` call. Then the listing will only fetch enough pages to get the first 100 rows.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, it does not get the top 100 server side. For that you need the [ListBlobsSegmented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmented?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobsSegmented_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_System_Nullable_System_Int32__Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobContinuationToken_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) method.

At it simplest it can look like this:

```
IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList = container.ListBlobsSegmented(string.Empty, true,
    BlobListingDetails.Metadata, 100, null, null, null).Results
    .OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified);
```

You can split the query in smaller chuncks and then use a [BlobContinuationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobcontinuationtoken?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) to iterate over the chunks. Look at the documentation I provided in this post for all the options.

Do mind however that it is not possible to sort the results serverside. It wil only sort the chunk you retrieve and client side only.

Comment: Peter is correct. Please note that there is no way to list blobs in the order of LastModified date from server side.

Comment: This isn't a complete solution for two reasons. First, it only gets and sorts the first page of results. Other results that come earlier in sort order might exist. Second, there is no guarantee that `ListBlobsSegmented` will return 100 results. You need a loop to get more results in case the first call didn't return enough.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT that is why I stated that this code example is the bare minimum and that you have to use the token to iterate, will edit the answer to make ik more clear about the sorting. Btw, if there are less than 100 items at the server do you still need to loop? I thought not but I might be wrong...

Comment: @Peter, you do still need to loop. The service can break up the result set in some cases.